# Getting Dropdownlist selected value in vb.net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, drop-down-menu, selectedvalue

I am trying to set user account for my system. I have two tables (User and Staff)

And this is the interface for setting up user
[image]

the name dropdownlist  need to be bound to staff table where I can display a list of staff members. When I insert these data to the user table I need to convert the selected staff name into its ID.

I'm really weak in programming and if possible help me with this.
this is the code I am using

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnUserAdd.Click
    If ValidData() Then
        Try
            cmd.Connection = con
            con.Open()
            sel_id = Convert.ToString(cmbStaffName.SelectedValue)
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text
            cmd.CommandText = "Insert Into dbo.[User] (User_ID,Employee_ID,User_Name,Password,User_Level) values ('" & txtBoxUserID.Text & "','" & sel_id & "','" & txtBoxUserName.Text & "', '" & txtBoxPassword.Text & "','" & ComboBox1.Text & "')"
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            MsgBox("Succesfully Added", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "add")

        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)

        End Try
        con.Close()
    End If

    If Not ValidData() Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub



Private Sub btnUserUpdate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnUserUpdate.Click

End Sub

Private Sub Setup_User_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'MyHotelManagementSystemDataSet19.Staff' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    Me.StaffTableAdapter1.Fill(Me.MyHotelManagementSystemDataSet19.Staff)
    'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'MyHotelManagementSystemDataSet18.Staff' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    Me.User_TypeTableAdapter.Fill(Me.MyHotelManagementSystemDataSet17.User_Type)

End Sub

Private Sub cmbStaffName_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmbStaffName.SelectedIndexChanged

    Try
        con.Open()
        ds = New DataSet()
        cmd = New SqlCommand("select * from Staff", con)
        Adapter = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
        adapter.Fill(ds)
        cmbStaffName.DataSource = StaffBindingSource1
        cmbStaffName.DisplayMember = "Name"
        cmbStaffName.ValueMember = "Employee_ID"

    Catch ex As Exception
    Finally
        con.Close()
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: what is the value of sel_id?

Comment: You didn't specify what problem you were facing? So. What is the problem you face?

Comment: And you were assign strange value to DataSource. Please note I have only looked at the 'Bind staff to DDL' part of your question. Because I am not sure what problems you have here. Till you specify them of course.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Private Sub cmbStaffName_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmbStaffName.SelectedIndexChanged

        Try
            con.Open()
            ds = New DataSet()
            cmd = New SqlCommand("select * from Staff", con)
            Using adapter as New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)  
                 adapter.Fill(ds)
            End Using

            cmbStaffName.DisplayMember = "Name"
            cmbStaffName.ValueMember = "Employee_ID"
            cmbStaffName.DataSource = ds


        Catch ex As Exception
        Finally
            con.Close()
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Comment: I get this error message when I try to add new user,"INSERT Statement conflicted with the foreign key constraint "FK_User_Staff". The conflict occurred in database 'Hotel Management System'table dbo.Staff,column Employee_ID. The statement has been terminated. And also When I put cmbStaffNme.DataBind() it gives an error as DataBind is not a memeber of System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox

Comment: When inserting in which Table? Are you talking about the Insert statement you have posted where you are inserting into User? That user table should not have a Foreign key, correct? User's employee_ID should be in the Staff table and are you insert into staff? Check the ID you are passing as Foreign key exists in its reference table.

Comment: I am sorry about the DataBind() that is for Webforms. My bad.

Comment: Also, why are you even binding it inside the selected index change? Shouldn't it be bound to the dropdownlist when this form is accessed? The list should be populated right from the start.